# socket stops after first receive

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a BackGroundWorker that i use to listen in a port
It works pretty well, the problems is that after the first receiving it stops working, i tried with a "**while(true)**" and restarting it in the **RunWorkerComplete** event but had no success
With stopPoints i can see that it does a console.writeline() with the correct message, then it stops working

```
    using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{

    private static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program P = new Program();

        P.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        P.ipaddress = IPAddress.Any;
        P.tcpServer = new TcpServer(P.ipaddress.ToString(), 3001);

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        //worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        if (!worker.IsBusy) worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit the server.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         IPEndPoint endPoint;
        Socket tcpClient;
        Socket listener;
        int pendingConnectionQueueSize;
        IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Any;

        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 3001);

        pendingConnectionQueueSize = 100;
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(endPoint);
        listener.Listen(pendingConnectionQueueSize);

        Console.WriteLine("conn..");
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[4096];
        tcpClient = listener.Accept();
        tcpClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

        while (true)
        {
            int rc = tcpClient.Receive(receiveBuffer);
             string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer);

            if (rc == 0)
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(msg.Trim());
        }

        listener.Close();
    }
    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!worker.IsBusy) worker.RunWorkerAsync();//restart

    }

}
```

Comment: note, the current code is just wrong *anyway*; you should only be looking at `GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, rc)`, and even that only when `rc > 0`; the `Trim()` is working by accident - it won't do the right thing in the normal case. Fortunately this is ASCII, otherwise there would be a lot more complications; however! is more data actually being sent to the server *on the same connection*?

Comment: also note: any time I see a socket server being written with sync reads, I get very nervous; it would be *really, really easy* to overwhelm this server - if it is just to handle one or two concurrent clients, fine I guess...

Comment: testing locally with telnet, it is working "well enough"; it is definitely reading more than once

Comment: Yo may have a KeepAlive where the size of the data is zero.  So the error is in the if(rc == 0) break;.  Remove the break and see if it works.

Comment: this is a minor tweak I have locally; but to emphasize: it is reading multiple times quite happily, and always was: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/342631cf928d08cfb45f82adbf1079b3

Comment: @jdweng that would be very bad; that will mean it enters into a hot loop whenever a client disconnects - good for heating up the server room, I guess? (yes, zero-length reads are possible for checking availability, but: this isn't a zero-length read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then it stops working

The code shown works, and reads as many times as data is available; I tested it with telnet, and it worked fine (ish - there are still some bugs around the ASCII decode of the buffer, as discussed in comments)!

If it is only reading once, then I can only assume that your *client* isn't sending more data *on the same connection*. The code shown only accepts one connection, and then reads it to the end.